# Bootstrap - using only the first 6 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap is it ok if I write this code, to use only 6 columns in a row?
What happens with the other 6 columns?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">some text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The rest 6 cols remain empty . Check this https://jsfiddle.net/7vt0r2nb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is OK, there no need to write 12 column if you will take col-4 and col-2 it will take 50% width and rest 50% width will be remain blank.